# excel data validation using single criteria in table

Tags: excel

This seems a straightforward requirement but I'm struggling to find an answer.

I have a simple table with a column listing product codes and another column listing whether it is active or not.

On a separate sheet, I want to use data validation to only list those products which are active.

I have found a number of examples which would require an initial selection of Yes/No for the status, which would then filter the list but I just want the list pre-filtered to show only the active products.

Is there a formula I can use in Data Validation which allows a preset criteria?

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: If you found a good example for Yes/No, why can it not be used for Active/Not ?

Comment: it requires a separate drop down to initially choose yes or no, I just need to be able to list the active products and not give the user the option to select inactive products.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more research I found the answer using OFFSET, MATCH and COUNTIF.

With a data validation type of List, the following formula only displays the rows where cell to the left (range named Active_Prod in this case) says Yes.

=OFFSET(Active_Prod,MATCH("Yes",Active_Prod,0)-1,1,COUNTIF(Active_Prod,"Yes"),1)

Hopefully this is of use to others.

Comment: After further testing, I have found that named ranges need to be wrapped by INDIRECT and the results aren't consist.  Having Yes in 4 rows lists the first 4 products, not the products which have Yes next to the code.  Any suggestions?